# MSIX issue with accessing multiple executables in one WinApp solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msix

I have a visual studio solution, with two projects.

```
Solution
--> project_a (main)
--> project_b
```

project_a, is dependent on project_b. There is a post build event, that moves project_b.exe, into project_a's output directory. Project_a then launches a few instances of project_b.exe to do its thing.

All is working fine when I run my application normally. But when I package my application into an MSIX bundle, project_a.exe cannot find and locate the project_b.exe binary.

In c:\programfiles\WindowsApps<myapp>, I can see that project_a and project_b are in different directories, and the project_b.exe binary hasn't been moved into the project_a directory like it is when I run it locally.

I also tried to dynamically access the probect_b binary in its different path, but when I do that I get an System.UnauthorizedAccessException. I assume because windows isolates both the projects.

Any idea's how I fix this?

Comment: I too have the same problem; I have a launcher app, and the main app. I want bot apps to be located in one folder.